# In this multithreaded java application only one thread seems to be running like a sequential program?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Sorry for lengthy description. If it's too long please tell me how to improve.

I am learning about Java concurrency. This is a scenario I tried to code.

A mother and a child share a bank account. Mother and child are two separate threads and are started from the main thread of the program.

In the run() of both, they perform several bank transactions. For simplicity, the child does only withdraw transactions and mother does only deposit transactions. Each transaction is also a separate thread. Child/Mother have to wait until one transaction is complete to start the next. (wait/notifyAll used for this).

If a withdrawal task tries to withdraw but there is an insufficient balance (balance is 0 initially) then the thread goes to a while loop waiting till the balance becomes greater than withdrawal amount.

Mother sleeps 500ms between each deposit task.

**What I expected**

Since the mother sleeps between every deposit and the child doesn't sleep during withdrawals it is guaranteed that the child's tasks will enter the `insufficient funds while loop`. However, since the mother is a separate thread, after waiting 500ms it will deposit some money. Then the child's withdrawal task thread will notice this, get out of the while loop and complete the transaction.

**What happens**

Child goes to a infinite loop trying to withdraw. Mother's thread does not deposit.

I have a hunch that this is something to do with  wait(). When I call task.wait() from child, it is waiting for this specific instance of Task class to call notify() right? Not all instances of Task class.

[image]

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account();
        new Child("Bob", account).start();
        new Mother("mary", account).start();

    }
}

class Child extends Thread {
    String name;
    Account account;

    public Child(String name, Account account) {
        super("Child");
        this.name = name;
        this.account = account;
    }

    private void transaction(int val, TaskType taskType) {
        Task task = new Task(account, taskType, val);
        task.start();
        synchronized (task) {
            try {
                task.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.transaction(100, TaskType.WITHDRAW);
        System.out.println("100 WITHDRAW");
        this.transaction(150, TaskType.WITHDRAW);
        System.out.println("150 WITHDRAW");
        this.transaction(200, TaskType.WITHDRAW);
        System.out.println("200 WITHDRAW");
        this.transaction(500, TaskType.WITHDRAW);
        System.out.println("500 WITHDRAW");
    }
}

class Mother extends Thread {
    String name;
    Account account;

    public Mother(String name, Account account) {
        super("Mother");
        this.name = name;
        this.account = account;
    }

    private void transaction(int val, TaskType taskType) {
        Task task = new Task(account, taskType, val);
        task.start();
        synchronized (task) {
            try {
                task.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.transaction(100, TaskType.DEPOSIT);
        System.out.println("100 DEPOSIT");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.transaction(150, TaskType.DEPOSIT);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("150 DEPOSIT");
        this.transaction(200, TaskType.DEPOSIT);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("200 DEPOSIT");
        this.transaction(500, TaskType.DEPOSIT);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("500 DEPOSIT");
    }
}

class Task extends Thread {
    private static int id = 0;
    Account account;
    TaskType taskType;
    int val;

    public Task(Account account, TaskType taskType, int val) {
        super("Task");
        this.account = account;
        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch (taskType) {
            case WITHDRAW:
                account.withdraw(val, id);
                break;
            case DEPOSIT:
                account.deposit(val, id);
                break;
        }
        id += 1;
    }
}

class Account {
    int balance = 0;

    public synchronized void deposit(int val, int id) {
        this.balance += val;
        this.notifyAll();

    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(int val, int id) {
        while (this.balance < val) {
            System.out.println("Funds insufficient waiting..." + id);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.balance -= val;
        System.out.println("Withdrawal successful " + id);
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}

enum TaskType {
    DEPOSIT,
    WITHDRAW
}
```

**Update - synchronized on account object instead of task**

```
private void transaction(int val, TaskType taskType) {
    Task task = new Task(account, taskType, val);
    task.start();
    synchronized (account) {
        try {
            account.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Did for both Mother and Child. I'm getting the same output.

Comment: In addition to the other concerns, `System.out.println` is synchronized internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mother` and `Child` threads are waiting on the same `task` object, so they will wake up if you call `task.notifyAll()`. However, that's not what's happening. It is the `account` that calls `notifyAll` when more money is deposited.

The main problem with this implementation is that task is a separate thread. If you still want to keep it that way, then this is what you can do:

First: Account.withdraw waits with a `Sleep`. Instead, it should use `wait()`, so when `Account.deposit` calls `notifyAll`, it can wake up.

Your `Mother` and `Child` threads can wait on `task`, but then `task` has to notify them. So at the end of `Task.run` you should call `notifyAll` to wake up any threads waiting on the task.

You are essentially using three threads to run a sequential task.

Comment: Hi, did what you suggest. Still getting the same response. Updated code in question.

Comment: I think I see what's wrong. I  changed my answer. The Mother and Child should still wait for Task, but then Task has to wait on Account.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you :)